# How do i validate a company email using php preg_match function

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to use the preg_match function in php to validate a company email. I have done some general email  validation using the same function before but in this case i want the pattern to suit this company email format below
something**@brainstake.tech**

Below is my code snippet, kindly Help me correct the pattern so that it suits my company email format.

```
private function validateEmail(){  
        $result = null;  
        //$pattern1 = "/^[_a-z0-9-+]+(\.[_a-z0-9-+]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$/i";//for all email types  
        $pattern = "/^[_a-z0-9-+]+(\.[_a-z0-9-+]+)*@[brainstake-]*(\.[tech]{2,})$/i";   //for brainstake emails  
        if (!preg_match($pattern, $this->email)){  
            $result = false;  
            echo "Only Brainstake company emails are allowed.";  
        }  
        else{  
            $result = true;  
        }  
        return $result;  
    }  

if ($this->validateEmail() == false){  
    echo "Please use correct email";  
    header("location: ../pages/sign-up.php?error=wrongEmailFormat");  
    exit();  
}
```

Result: /sign-up.php?error=wrongEmailFormat

Comment: As you want a fixed part of the string, something like `^[_a-z0-9-+]+(\.[_a-z0-9-+]+)*@brainstake\.tech$

Comment: what about using a simple filter_var and a silly explode by @?

Comment: Do you realize that his code `echo "Please use correct email";  
    header("location: ../pages/sign-up.php?error=wrongEmailFormat");` makes no sense?

Comment: How did you even try to understand regular expressions when you put everything into square brackets? Also reading `if (... == false)` tells me you're not only a beginner in regex but also in programming.